# Is there a default label for the built-in RSA-OAEP encryption in Java?

Tags: rsa, public-key

I am implementing my own version of RSA-OAEP with SHA-256. I want to test it by comparing it to the output of the Cipher class in Java using RSA-OAEP and SHA-256. According to PKCS #1, RSA-OAEP requires a label, which by default is an empty string. However, I can't find a way to input a label in the built-in class. My implementation seems to work correctly for both encryption and decryption, but Cipher class produces different output. Is there a default label which the Cipher class uses?

Answer (score 2):

What is called label L in PKCS1v2.1 RSAES-OAEP was called encoding parameters P in v2.0; see the description of pSourceAlgorithm in A.2.1. The Java API keeps the old terminology, presumably for compatibility, and the default is indeed an empty octet string, implemented in Java as a `byte` array of length 0. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PSource.PSpecified.html . Note that even when P-call-me-L is empty, its *hash* which goes in DB before masking is not empty.

When you say 'different output', you do realize that OAEP is randomized (in a way that provably does not leak information to the adversary) and every encryption of the same plaintext should produce a unique ciphertext, but all of them should decrypt back to the same plaintext, right?